# PowerShell does not automatically import function

Tags: powershell

I had the issue, that one function of a PowerShell module was wrongly implicitly imported.

1. get-command  did return, that the function does not exist
2. get-help  | fl * returns, that the functions does exists in an other module - where the function is definitely not defined
3. The function looks "broken", there where no parameters
4. Intelisense also had the function without parameters
5. explicit import with import-module - all fine

Did have this issue with PowerShell 5.1 in all consoles (ISE, Console, VSCode)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in the module analysis cache. I deleted the cache and all works fine.
Path to cache is in $env:PSModuleAnalysisCachePath

More information is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/wmf/whats-new/release-notes?view=powershell-7.1#module-analysis-cache